# How to only check one layer in a group at a time?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, table-of-contents

I have a group of layers and in my plugin, I would only like **one layer from a specific group to be checked at any time**. The plugin contains a toggle button which connects each layer to a function. The function finds the checked layer and adds it to a list, it then finds all other layers and I tried to set their node state to `Unchecked` but clearly I'm missing something.

Here is the code:

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
group = root.findGroup('Main group')

def check():
    if self.plugin_button.isChecked():
        # Create empty list to contain checked layer
        layer_list = []
        for child in group.children():
            node = root.findLayer(child.layer().id()) 
            if node.isVisible():
                # Add checked layer into list
                layer_list.append(node.name())
            # For layers not in list
            if child.name() not in layer_list:
                ###### Not sure what to do here ######
                node = root.findLayer(child.layer().id()) 
                node.setVisible(Qt.Unchecked)
                iface.legendInterface().setLayerVisible(child.layer(), False)
    else:
        for layers in group.children():
            # Disconnect layers in group from function
            layers.visibilityChanged.disconnect(check)

# Connect layers in group to function
for layers in group.children():
    layers.visibilityChanged.connect(check)
```

---

**Update:**

Made some progress, the following code now only allows one layer to be active at any time. Only issue is when a layer is checked, clicking on any layer unchecks all layers. Still looking to see how to keep one layer checked at all times. Also if a layer is checked, I don't want it unchecked (i.e. I want it *'locked'*). The only way to uncheck it is to select another layer.

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
group = root.findGroup('Main group')

def check(layer):
    if self.plugin_button.isChecked():                
        layer_list = []
        layer_list.append(layer.name())
        for child in group.children():
            if child.name() not in layer_list:
                iface.legendInterface().setLayerVisible(child.layer(), False) 
    else:
        for layers in group.children():
            layers.visibilityChanged.disconnect(check)

# Connect layers in group to function
for layers in group.children():
    layers.visibilityChanged.connect(check)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disconnect the function from each layer ***before*** using `setLayerVisible`. Then perform the logic of only activating one layer at a time and then reconnect the function. The clicked layer will always be active (i.e. there will always be one layer active in the group at all times):

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
group = root.findGroup('Main group')

def check(layer):
    # Store clicked layer's name in list
    layer_list = []
    layer_list.append(layer.name())     
    # Clicked layer will always be visible
    iface.legendInterface().setLayerVisible(layer, True) 
    for layers in group.children():
        # Disconnect slot from signal
        layers.visibilityChanged.disconnect(check)
        if layers.name() not in layer_list:
            # If layers not in list (i.e. not selected), set visible to False
            iface.legendInterface().setLayerVisible(layers.layer(), False) 
        # Reconnect slot to signal
        layers.visibilityChanged.connect(check)

# Connect layers in group to function
for layers in group.children():
    layers.visibilityChanged.connect(check)
```